# Comparing two dates with different years

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to compare two dates for example today's date (`20/12/2016`) with a date from next year (`01/01/2017`). The code works fine if `RenewalDate` is for this year for example `22/12/2016`. It only seems to be if the date is for next year that it doesn't recognize that today is not greater than that date

```
var RenewalDate = new Date(result.RenewalDate);
var month = RenewalDate.getMonth()+1;
var year = RenewalDate.getFullYear();
if(day<10){
    day='0'+day
} 
if(month<10){
   month='0'+month
} 
var RenewalDate = day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
       dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
      mm='0'+mm
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
if(today > RenewalDate)
{
   alert("Date is greater than today");
}
else
{
    alert("Date is less than today");
}
```

Comment: why dont you create date object from these two dates ?

Comment: simply create two date objects. `new Date()` and `new Date('1/1/2017')` and compare with if condition

Comment: Comparing dd/mm/yyyy as string would also fail if the day is later, eg 01/12/2016 would be before 02/01/2016.  If you don't want to create a `Date` then format your date strings as ansi format, ie:  `var today = yyyy+mm+dd` and compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert the date to string to compare as you did since it will do the `string` comparison instead of `date` comparison. If you did, even it will treat `22/11/2016` is greater than `20/12/2016` within the same year.

You can simply use either `today > renewalDate` or `today.getTime() > renewalDate.getTime()` as below,

**Method 1**:

```js
var renewalDate = new Date(2017, 0, 1);
var today = new Date();

if(today > renewalDate)
{
   alert("Date is greater than today");
}
else
{
    alert("Date is less than today");
}
```

**Method 2**:

```js
    var renewalDate = new Date(2017, 0, 1);
    var today = new Date();

    if(today.getTime() > renewalDate.getTime())
    {
       alert("Date is greater than today");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Date is less than today");
    }
```

**Note**: Method 1 and Method 2 will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

```
moment('2016-12-20').isAfter('2016-01-02', 'year'); // false
moment('2016-12-20').isAfter('2015-12-31', 'year'); // true
```

Comment: The OP hasn't put moment in the answer or added a tag. A library really isn't needed to use an equality operator. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code instead what you are doing,

```
var to = new Date(2016,12,12);
var from = new Date(2017,12,12);
if(to > from){
 alert('to is greater than from');
}else{
     alert('to is less than from');
}
```

I hope this sample code will work your requirement

Answer (score -1):

Technically you are comparing strings not the dates, compare any two date objects you will get correct results or convert it to timestamps `date.getTime()` (it is long number), and then compare you will get correct results.

Comment: But string comparison is different.

Comment: In case of string comparison `31/01/2000` is bigger than `01/01/2016`.

Comment: I think you missed my point. 12 January 2015, 2015-W03-1 and 1420984800000 are all timestamps. ;-)

Comment: Actually timestamp should not associate with timezone, but the string dates in javascript are associated with timezone see the below example          `new Date("01/01/2016");
Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`  It has IST / GMGT+0530 is at the end says it is associated with timezone. But if you use the milliseconds it will be independent of timezone.

Comment: "*timestamp should not associate with timezone*", is incorrect, you misunderstand what a [*timestamp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is. '*string dates in javascript are associated with timezone*" maybe, the result of *Date.prototype.toString* is entirely implementation dependent and may or may not have a timezone. What does *toLocaleString* return? Time values (e.g. the result of *getTime*) are **specified** as being UTC, which is effectively any timezone with offset 00:00 (e.g. GMT).

Comment: Yes, I understand, what I meant is  Lets consider timestamp is  simple sequence number, if you have string date in javascript, then you need location/timezone to get to know the time accurately, and the string time may repeats(Eg. 10.30PM @ GMT+0000 will repeat for 10.30PM @ GMT+0300), But the milliseconds(long number result of date.getTime() )  will never repeat, And it is sequence of time irrespective of the geographical location.